# An Algebraic Characterization of a Space Associated with Krylov Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $\mathcal{X}$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and let $x_0 \in \mathcal{X} \setminus \{0_{\mathcal{X}}\}$ (here, $0_{\mathcal{X}}$ denotes the zero vector in $\mathcal{X}$). We denote by $\textrm{End}(\mathcal{X}),$ the following set:
$$ \textrm{End}(\mathcal{X}) = \{ T : \mathcal{X} \rightarrow \mathcal{X} \, | \, T~\textrm{is linear} \}. $$
Traditionally (and as defined by J. S. Golan in "The Linear Algebra a Beginning Graduate Student Ought to Know" (3ed) - Page 297), for any $T \in \textrm{End}(\mathcal{X})$ with $T^{0} \equiv \textrm{Id}_{\mathcal{X}}$ (the identity operator on $\mathcal{X}$), the subspace
$$ \mathscr{K}(x_0, T) = \textrm{span}\{ x_0, T x_0, T^{2} x_0, \dots \} = \textrm{span}\{ T^{n} x_0 \}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} $$
is called the $\textit{Krylov subspace}$ of $\mathcal{X}$ defined by $T$ and $x_0$ (here, for any $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \},$ $T^{k} \equiv \underset{k~\textrm{times}}{\underbrace{T \circ T \circ \cdots \circ T}}$). Additionally, for any strictly positive integer $m,$ we also write

$$\mathscr{K}_{m}(x_0, T) = \textrm{span}\{ x_0, T x_0, T^{2} x_0, \dots, T^{m-1} x_0 \} \subset \mathcal{X}.$$

$\textbf{Question}$:

Let $n$ and $k$ be strictly positive integers. Additionally, let $\mathcal{X} = \mathbb{C}^{n},$ let $\mathbf{x}_0 \in \mathcal{X},$ and let $T \equiv \mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}.$ Associated with $\mathscr{K}_{k}(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{A})$ is the $\textit{Krylov matrix},$ $\mathbf{K}_{k,(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{A})}$:
$$ \mathbf{K}_{k,(\mathbf{x}_0, \mathbf{A})} = [ \mathbf{x}_0 \, | \, \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_0 \, | \, \mathbf{A}^2 \mathbf{x}_0 \, | \, \cdots \, | \, \mathbf{A}^{k-1} \mathbf{x}_0 ] \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times k} \equiv \mathcal{Y}. $$
Is there a proper way to write the space $\mathcal{Y} \equiv \mathbb{C}^{n \times k}$ in terms of the space $\mathcal{X}?$

For example, if

$$ \mathcal{Y} = \ell^{2}(\mathbb{N}; \mathbb{C}) = \left\{ (\xi_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \mathbb{C}^{\mathbb{N}} \, \middle| \, \sum\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |\xi_n|^2 < +\infty \right\}, $$

if $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{H}_{i} = \mathbb{C}$ and if $\|\cdot\|_{i} \equiv |\cdot|$ for every $i \in \mathbb{N},$ one can "combine" the family of vector (Hilbert) spaces $(\mathcal{H}_{i}, \|\cdot\|_{i})_{ i\in \mathbb{N}}$ via the (Hilbert) direct sum

$$ \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X} = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{H}_{i } = \left\{ (x_i)_{ i \in \mathbb{N}} \in \times_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \mathcal{H}_{i } \, \middle| \, \sum\limits_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \| x_i \|^2_i < +\infty \right\}. $$

In this case, one has $\mathcal{Y} = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{X}.$

Granted, this is a different notion of "combining" vector spaces, but I only list it here for reference (perhaps one can "combine" $\mathcal{X}$ in such a way that it is isomorphic to $\mathcal{Y}$).

Again, any suggestions or references in the direction of more information would be very helpful.